# Unable to display pdf using JoanZapata android-pdfview -app crashing

Tags: android, pdf

I am working on an android application where I want to display a pdf in the same application itself so I downloaded the latest `android-pdfview-1.0.4.jar` [from here](http://search.maven.org/android-pdfview) and I also downloaded all the required libraries as shown in the image below from here github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview/libs

[image]

This is my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnLoadCompleteListener, OnPageChangeListener, OnDrawListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PDFView pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);

        pdfView.fromAsset("sample.pdf")
                .defaultPage(1)
                .showMinimap(false)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .load();;
    }



    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float v, float v1, int i) {

    }
}
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also added the required dependency In my `Build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/android-pdfview-1.0.4.jar')
}
```

I have also added an `assets folder` and added one pdf in it - `sample.pdf`

Now everytime I am trying to run my application , the app is crashing

```
11-20 17:48:42.000  14517-14526/? E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-20 17:48:42.000  14517-14526/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
11-20 17:48:42.126  14517-14536/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.test.pdf, PID: 14517
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.pdf-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libvudroid.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
            at org.vudroid.core.VuDroidLibraryLoader.load(VuDroidLibraryLoader.java:13)
            at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfContext.<clinit>(PdfContext.java:13)
            at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:50)
            at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:31)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please help.

Comment: I found the solution by adding the native lib folders in `\app\src\main\jniLibs` folder... We have to create this `jni` folder in `main` and add the folders `arm64-v8a` ,`armeabi`,`armeabi-v7a`,`mips`,`x86` into it